# Any way to keep Stunnel from blowing up my logfiles?

Tags: linux, rsyslog, syslog-ng, stunnel

I have *stunnel* v5.44 (Ubuntu 18.04 v3:5.44-1ubuntu3) configured on a client to connect to a server in a screened subnet. The remote host has syslog configured to listen for logfiles over the *stunnel* connection. The client, of course, is configured to forward it's logs to the server over *stunnel*.

This setup has worked great for years, but sometime last year (or year before? *gawd* 2020...), during OS upgrades (Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04), something changed where stunnel is now spamming the logfiles with **hundreds** of error messages **per second** whenever the remote syslog server is rebooted or unavailable.

```
...
Jan 20 04:20:31 nwhost stunnel[25787]: LOG5[2126349]: Connection reset: 0 byte(s) sent to TLS, 0 byte(s) sent to socket
Jan 20 04:20:31 nwhost stunnel[25787]: LOG5[2126350]: Service [syslog_tunnel] accepted connection from 127.0.0.1:52970
Jan 20 04:20:31 nwhost stunnel[25787]: LOG3[2126350]: s_connect: connect 172.22.15.23:51400: Connection refused (111)
Jan 20 04:20:31 nwhost stunnel[25787]: LOG3[2126350]: No more addresses to connect
Jan 20 04:20:31 nwhost stunnel[25787]: LOG5[2126350]: Connection reset: 0 byte(s) sent to TLS, 0 byte(s) sent to socket
Jan 20 04:20:31 nwhost stunnel[25787]: LOG5[2126351]: Service [syslog_tunnel] accepted connection from 127.0.0.1:52974
Jan 20 04:20:31 nwhost stunnel[25787]: LOG3[2126351]: s_connect: connect 172.22.15.23:51400: Connection refused (111)
Jan 20 04:20:31 nwhost stunnel[25787]: LOG3[2126351]: No more addresses to connect
...
```

In my clientside `/etc/stunnel/remote_log.conf` I have this, but the errors keep filling up the logs:

```
client   = yes
cert     = /etc/stunnel/shared/stunnel.pem
pid      = /var/run/stunnel4/syslog_stunnel.pid
syslog   = no
output   = /var/log/stunnel4/stunnel.log

[syslog_tunnel]
accept   = 127.0.0.1:5140
connect  = 172.22.15.23:51400
```

I thought `syslog = no` would disable logging (man page) but it doesn't. Anyone know of a config that works or something to disable the spammy logging altogether?

Answer (score 1):

As per man page

> `syslog = yes | no` (Unix only)
>
> ```
>       enable logging via syslog
> ```

which mean `stunnel` will be logged or not as per your syslog on server configuration, that is mean if set to `no` nothing from stunnel to syslog will be sent however you may change the

```
output   = /dev/null
```

or lower the debug level to 0

```
debug = 0
```